# The name does not exist in current context - How to access it?

Tags: c#, .net

In my code i have defined string repeatnumber and assigned it into for loop. However, i need it to be accesible when im creating a button click event. Not sure how to do it.

Can anyone give me some tips?

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {         
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] assignments = new string[] { "A", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
        Random rnd = new Random();

        string[] randomingArray = assignments.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        string repeatNumber = "";

        List<ImageSource> animals = new List<ImageSource>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                repeatNumber = randomingArray[i % randomingArray.Length];
                animals.Add(new ImageSource() { Source = repeatNumber, Number = i });
            }
            else if ((i % 9) == 0)
            {
                animals.Add(new ImageSource() { Source = repeatNumber, Number = i });
            }
            else
            {
                animals.Add(new ImageSource() { Source = randomingArray[i % rnd.Next(1,5)], Number = i });
            }
            ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = animals;
        }
    }


    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((new ImageSource() { Source = repeatNumber })); <-- the name repeatNumber does not exist in current context
    }
}

class ImageSource
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `repeatnumber` as a class property

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   private string repeatNumber;

   public MainWindow()
   {  
   ...
```

Otherwise it is limited to the scope (<= you want to look that up) of the `MainWindow` constructor.